# Can I POST to a template?

Tags: templating

In the documentation "search form" example you can run a GET request to a specific template and if you use a Plugin you can run a POST request to a specific controller action.

But is it possible to run a POST request directly to a template?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, works just the same. Just change method="GET" to method="POST".

You can acquire the POST values by using `craft()->request->getPost('yourPostName')` in your plugin controller or by using `{{ craft.request.getPost('yourPostName') }}` in a template.

Comment: Ehh... I tried this and template stopped working. That's why I made this post. What could I have done wrong? Hehe :)

Comment: Could you post the part of your template responsible for this?